# Unable to link/include CFITSIO library

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, astronomy

I have successfully  compiled CIFITSIO using the instuctions in the following link:  https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/quick/node3.html . However I'm unable to include/link the library, it reports the following error "fitsio.h is not found" after running the C program. Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu(installed using WSL). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you didn't build it with sudo,
The library should be installed globally in a system directory and It should be accessible, also when you are linking your library against your C program, you should use -L options to determine from where to link libraries and -I from where to include header files. There must be several problems.